# editing fields at the same time with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twig

Current Scenario :

I am getting frusturated for few days and right now I don't know what to do anymore basically I have a form in which you can edit and save each records of input fields. i.e. firstName, lastName, etc.. I do not get any errors and everything is working fine.

Requirement :

Now what I want to save & edit firstName and lastName input fields together instead is to edit and save firstName and lastName input field sepeately. Right now they are all different input id's.

Question :

How can I achieve this by calling the same class for firstName and lastName if I want to edit them at the same time with a button ?

how can I make this happen ? Thanks...

Code :

```
{{ form_start(form,{'multipart':'true','attr':{'class':'myform'}}) }}
  <label>First Name</label><br/>
  {{ form_widget(form.userinfo.firstName,{'id':'inputName','attr':{'class':'form-control inputName','placeholder':'name','disabled':'disabled'}}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.userinfo.firstName) }}
  <input type="button" value="Edit" id="inputName-edit" class="btn btn-game link-btn" data="inputName"/>
  <input type="button" value="Done" id="inputName-save" class="btn btn-game link-btn-save" data="inputName"/>

  <label>Last Name</label><br/>
  {{ form_widget(form.userinfo.lastName,{'id':'lastName','attr':{'class':'form-control lastName','placeholder':'Last name','disabled':'disabled'}}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.userinfo.lastName) }}
  <input type="button" value="Edit" id="lastName-edit" class="btn btn-game link-btn" data="lastName"/>
  <input type="button" value="Done" id="lastName-save" class="btn btn-game link-btn-save" data="lastName"/>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

js

```
$("#inputName,#lastName").on('keypress',function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var field = $(this).attr("id");
            var data = {};
            data['ajax']=true;
            data[$('#'+field).attr('name')]=$('#'+field).val();
            $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: this.form.action,
                    data: data
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    if(msg['status']=='fail'){
                        $('#errormsg span').html(msg['msg']);
                        $('#errormsg').show();
                    }
                    if($('#'+field).attr('name')=='game_user_profile[userinfo][firstName]')  {
                        $('#userfirstname').text($('#'+field).val());
                    }
                    if($('#'+field).attr('name')=='game_user_profile[userinfo][lastName]')  {
                        $('#userlastname').text($('#'+field).val());
                    }

                });

            $('#'+field+'-edit').show();
            $('#'+field+'-save').hide()
            $('#'+field).attr('disabled',true);
        }
});




//input enable and disable
$('.link-btn').click(function(){
        var field = $(this).attr("data");
        $('#'+field).attr('disabled',false).focus();
        $('#'+field+'-save').show();
        $(this).hide();

});

$(".link-btn-save").click(function(){
        var field = $(this).attr("data");
        var data = {};
        data['ajax']=true;
        data[$('#'+field).attr('name')]=$('#'+field).val();
        $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: this.form.action,
                  data: data
                })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    if(msg['status']=='fail'){
                      $('#errormsg span').html(msg['msg']);
                      $('#errormsg').show();
                    }
                      if($('#'+field).attr('name')=='game_user_profile[userinfo][firstName]')  {
                          $('#userfirstname').text($('#'+field).val());
                      }
                      if($('#'+field).attr('name')=='game_user_profile[userinfo][lastName]')  {
                          $('#userlastname').text($('#'+field).val());
                      }
              });

        $('#'+field+'-edit').show();
        $(this).hide()
        $('#'+field).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

I want it like this

```
{{ form_start(form,{'multipart':'true','attr':{'class':'myform'}}) }}
  <label>First Name</label><br/>
  {{ form_widget(form.userinfo.firstName,{'id':'inputName','attr':{'class':'form-control inputName','placeholder':'name','disabled':'disabled'}}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.userinfo.firstName) }}


  <label>Last Name</label><br/>
  {{ form_widget(form.userinfo.lastName,{'id':'lastName','attr':{'class':'form-control lastName','placeholder':'Last name','disabled':'disabled'}}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.userinfo.lastName) }}

  <input type="button" value="Edit" id="inputName-edit" class="btn btn-game link-btn" data="inputName"/>
  <input type="button" value="Done" id="inputName-save" class="btn btn-game link-btn-save" data="inputName"/>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: recreate it in https://jsfiddle.net/ and you may bet more answers.